# Boto3, how to disable ACL when using generate_presigned_url?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3

I keep getting this error:

**An error occurred (AccessControlListNotSupported) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket does not allow ACLs**

I'm switching to chunked uploads, previously i could do below and this uploaded fine.

```
original = models.FileField(storage=S3Boto3Storage(bucket_name='video-sftp',default_acl=None),upload_to='', blank=False, null=False)
```

Now i'm using generate_presigned_url and the ACL parameter is being ignored.

```
 url = client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod="put_object",
            Params={
                "Bucket": "video-sftp",
                "Key": f"{json.loads(request.body)['fileName']}",
                "ACL": "None"
            },
            ExpiresIn=300,
        )
```

How do i solve?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73551886/2696165?

Answer (score 2):

I have omitted the parameter `ACL` entirely and it works:

```py
s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    'put_object',
    Params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': key}
)
```

If you want to use the `ACL` parameter, maybe you shouldn't set it to the string `"None"` and use the value `None` instead.