# Unable to create invalidation in CloudFont from github actions. [not authorized because no identity-based policy]

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create an invalidation as part of a ci pipeline.

Here is the [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/invalidate-aws-cloudfront) from the marketplace.

Here's the steps I've taken

- created a IAM **user**
- created **secrets** in github repo
- **added policy** to the IAM user using the Add permissions > Attach Policy Directly *option*. And visual editor created the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::000000:distribution/E000000000 "
        }
    ]
}
```

which looks like this in IAM

`create-invalidation  Customer managed    Directly`

- have the following inside the github actions yml file.

```
      - name: Invalidate CloudFront
        uses: chetan/invalidate-cloudfront-action@v2
        env:
          DISTRIBUTION: ${{ secrets.DISTRIBUTION }}
          PATHS: "/*"
          AWS_REGION: "us-east-1"
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET }}
```

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/my-user-id is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateInvalidation on resource: arn:aws:cloudfront::000000000000:distribution/*** because no identity-based policy allows the cloudfront:CreateInvalidation action
> Error: Process completed with exit code 254.

PS. I have blanked out account id, distribution id etc to 0000000 but they are correct values.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid third-party package for cache invalidation using following command.

```
  # Invalidate cloudfront cache
  - name: Invalidate CloudFront cache
    run: |
      aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${{ DISTRIBUTION_ID }} --paths "/*"
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
```

You can follow these two links to help you in the process:

1. https://www.alexhyett.com/github-actions-deploy-to-s3/
2. [getting "The bucket does not allow ACLs" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080354/getting-the-bucket-does-not-allow-acls-error)