# Service:Amazon S3, Message:The bucket does not allow ACLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a flask app that uses S3 (boto3 in flask) to store images on AWS elastic beanstalk .
It works with no issues.

When I change region in AWS console and set up a new elastic beanstalk environment and deploy the same application, I get the error message:

```
Service:Amazon S3, Message:The bucket does not allow ACLs
```

I created a new S3 bucket in the same region and still getting the same error.

Block public access is enabled in both buckets.
ACLs are disabled in both buckets.

Could someone please let me know if facing the same issue how they solved it?

Please note that, although I have tried to enable ACLs and it did not work, I wouldn't like in any case to simply enable ACL, given that my first bucket that has ACLs disabled works perfectly fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting "The bucket does not allow ACLs" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080354/getting-the-bucket-does-not-allow-acls-error)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Forgot to mention (now edited) that I tried it and it did not work. Anyways I do not think enabling ACLs is the ideal solution. Also, in the other region my app works fine.