# The bucket does not allow ACLs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, acl

I am trying to set up code pipeline to autodeploy my nodejs app on github on Elastic Beanstalk when changes are made. The app is also using s3 bucket to host user profile images. The access to the bucket is public and ACL is enabled. The problem is when code pipeline is attempting to deploy, it fails with error: "Deployment completed, but with errors: Failed to deploy application. Service:Amazon S3, Message:The bucket does not allow ACLs". I've searched for a fix everywhere but the issue persists. What should I do?

I've allowed all public access for the bucket and set the Object ownership to object writer.

Basically, I went through all the steps mentioned here: [getting "The bucket does not allow ACLs" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080354/getting-the-bucket-does-not-allow-acls-error)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.